# Swift - Daily Local Notification with Event

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my application users will set a time. On that time I need to send them a daily notification with the count of newly created appointments. For example assume there are 3 appointments having on "01-03-2017". So on that day, at a selected time user should get a notification mentioning that "you have 3 new appointments". Newly added appointments will be saved in local realm db.

Actually what I have to do is every day user mentioned time, there should be run a code segment and check whether are there any new appointments in db. If so need to fire local notification. Even app is close this should work. I saw that in Android we can do this using alarm manager. But in swift I didn't found a way to do this.

I am not a expert in swift. So appreciate if you can give me a solution with a explanation. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to run code at desired time, as iOS prevents from doing this.

Though, if the realm database is updated, it means the app is running at some point to add the new appointments.

When it occurs, you could have a function similar to the following to create a local notification

```
func createLocalNotification(atDate date: DateComponents, appointmentCount: Int) {
  var content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

  content.title "You have \(appointmentCount) appointment(s) today"
  content.badge: appointmentCount

  let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: false)
  let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification-request-\(date.day!)-\(date.month!)-\(date.year!)", content: content, trigger: trigger)

  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That mean we have to schedule notifications for feature dates as well? am I correct?

Comment: Yes. When an appointment comes in (after it is saved to realm for example), you can call this method, configuring a `DateComponents` object with the day, month, year, hour and minute when you want to notify the user that he has appointments.

Comment: Because the request is tagged with an identifier containing day, month and year, any futher call **for the same date** will override the previously added request (see [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649634-identifier))

Comment: Thanks. @tomahh I will try this.